# CollapsingToolbarLayout Scrolling Bug -Sometimes it'll stuck when scrolled up

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm creating a Scrolling Activity in my Android App.  The Activity has a CollapsingToolbarLayout with parallax effect.

When I scroll the layout below the appbarlayout up, it'll go up smoothly and the appbarlayout will be collapsed up to the title.The ImageView and the TextView will go up to the title. And when I scroll the layout back down, they'll all go back down to the beginning.

The bug is here:

when I running the activity on some devices, sometimes when I scroll it up, the layout will be stucked there up and down for seconds and then, back go to the top. 
And when I running the activity on some other devices, it'll be OK, nothing wrong happened.

The demo of this bug:  https://share.weiyun.com/1d797a4a92580e1595eacb226f9a92a3

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="nczz.cn.helloworld.ScrollingActivity"
    >
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:background="#FA7199"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <nczz.cn.widget.CollapsingImageTextLayout
            android:id="@+id/imageTextLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:title_id="@+id/test_title"
            app:text_id="@+id/test_text"
            app:img_scale="0.6"
            app:text_scale="0.6"
            app:text_margin_left="110dp"
            app:img_id="@+id/test_img"
            app:img_margin_left="55dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/test_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="#FA7199"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/return_btn"
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/left" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/test_img"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/test_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/test_img"
                android:text="MoveText"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                />

        </nczz.cn.widget.CollapsingImageTextLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <include
        android:id="@+id/includelayout"
        layout="@layout/content_scrolling"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the CollapsingImageTextLayout:

```
package nczz.cn.widget;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewParent;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import nczz.cn.helloworld.R;


/**
 * Created by yahui.hu on 2017/4/21.
 */

public class CollapsingImageTextLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    private AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener mOffsetChangedListener;

    private int mTitleId, mTextId, mImageId;
    private int mTitleMarginLeft, mTitleMarginTop, mImgMarginLeft, mImgMarginTop;
    private float mTextScale, mImgScale;
    private View mTitle, mImg, mText;
    private boolean isGetView = true;
    private int mTitleHeight = 0;


    public CollapsingImageTextLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CollapsingImageTextLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CollapsingImageTextLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.CollapsingImageLayout, defStyleAttr, 0);
        mTitleId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.CollapsingImageLayout_title_id, 0);
        mTextId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.CollapsingImageLayout_text_id, 0);
        mImageId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.CollapsingImageLayout_img_id, 0);
        mTextScale = a.getFloat(R.styleable.CollapsingImageLayout_text_scale, 0.4f);
        mImgScale = a.getFloat(R.styleable.CollapsingImageLayout_img_scale, 0.4f);
        mTitleMarginLeft = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CollapsingImageLayout_text_margin_left, 0);
        mTitleMarginTop = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CollapsingImageLayout_text_margin_top, 0);
        mImgMarginLeft = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CollapsingImageLayout_img_margin_left, 0);
        mImgMarginTop = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CollapsingImageLayout_img_margin_top, 0);
        a.recycle();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        getView();
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    private void getView() {
        if (!isGetView) {
            return;
        }
        if (mTitleId != 0) {
            mTitle = findViewById(mTitleId);
        }

        if (mTextId != 0) {
            mText = findViewById(mTextId);
        }

        if (mImageId != 0) {
            mImg = findViewById(mImageId);
        }
        isGetView = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

        if (mTitle != null) {
            getViewOffsetHelper(mTitle).onViewLayout(0, 0);
            setMinimumHeight(getHeightWithMargins(mTitle));
            mTitleHeight = mTitle.getHeight();
            this.bringChildToFront(mTitle);
        }

        if (mImg != null) {
            getViewOffsetHelper(mImg).onViewLayout(mImgMarginLeft, mImgMarginTop);
            this.bringChildToFront(mImg);
        }

        if (mText != null) {
            getViewOffsetHelper(mText).onViewLayout(mTitleMarginLeft, mTitleMarginTop);
            this.bringChildToFront(mText);
        }
    }

    static ViewHelper getViewOffsetHelper(View view) {
        ViewHelper offsetHelper = (ViewHelper) view.getTag(R.id.view_helper);
        if (offsetHelper == null) {
            offsetHelper = new ViewHelper(view);
            view.setTag(R.id.view_helper, offsetHelper);
        }
        return offsetHelper;
    }


    private static int getHeightWithMargins(@NonNull final View view) {
        final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = view.getLayoutParams();
        if (lp instanceof MarginLayoutParams) {
            final MarginLayoutParams mlp = (MarginLayoutParams) lp;
            return view.getHeight() + mlp.topMargin + mlp.bottomMargin;
        }
        return view.getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        ViewParent viewParent = getParent();
        if (viewParent instanceof AppBarLayout) {
            if (mOffsetChangedListener == null) mOffsetChangedListener = new OffsetListenerImp();
            ((AppBarLayout) viewParent).addOnOffsetChangedListener(mOffsetChangedListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        ViewParent viewParent = getParent();
        if (viewParent instanceof AppBarLayout) {
            ((AppBarLayout) viewParent).removeOnOffsetChangedListener(mOffsetChangedListener);
        }
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }


    final int getMaxOffsetForPinChild(View child) {
        final ViewHelper offsetHelper = getViewOffsetHelper(child);
        final LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
        return getHeight()
                - offsetHelper.getLayoutTop()
                - child.getHeight()
                - lp.bottomMargin;
    }

    static int constrain(int amount, int low, int high) {
        return amount < low ? low : (amount > high ? high : amount);
    }

    static int constrain(int amount, int low) {
        return amount < low ? low : amount;
    }

    private void setTopAndBottomOffset(View child, int verticalOffset) {
        ViewHelper viewHelper = (ViewHelper) child.getTag(R.id.view_helper);
        viewHelper.setTopAndBottomOffset(
                constrain(-verticalOffset, 0, getMaxOffsetForPinChild(child)));
        Log.e("setTopAndBottomOffset",""+-verticalOffset);
    }

    private void setTopAndBottomOffset(View child, int verticalOffset, float scale) {
        ViewHelper viewHelper = (ViewHelper) child.getTag(R.id.view_helper);
        viewHelper.setTopAndBottomOffset(
                constrain(-verticalOffset - getMaxOffset(viewHelper, scale),
                        0));
        //Log.e("setTopAndBottomOffset",""+-verticalOffset);
    }

    private void setLeftAndRightOffset(View child, int verticalOffset, float scale) {
        ViewHelper viewHelper = (ViewHelper) child.getTag(R.id.view_helper);
        int maxOffsetDistance = getMaxOffset(viewHelper, scale);
        int maxLeft = viewHelper.getLayoutLeft()
                + (viewHelper.getViewWidth() - viewHelper.getScaleViewWidth(scale))
                - viewHelper.getMarginTitleLeft();
        int realOffset = (int) (maxLeft * 1.0f / (maxOffsetDistance * 1.0f) * verticalOffset);
        realOffset = constrain(realOffset, -maxLeft, maxLeft);
        viewHelper.setLeftAndRightOffset(realOffset);
       // Log.e("setLeftAndRightOffset",""+realOffset);
    }

    private void setViewScale(View child, int verticalOffset, float scale) {
        ViewHelper viewHelper = (ViewHelper) child.getTag(R.id.view_helper);
        int maxOffsetDistance = getMaxOffset(viewHelper, scale);
        float realScale = -verticalOffset - maxOffsetDistance > 0 ? scale : verticalOffset == 0 ? 1f : 0f;
        if (realScale == 0) {
            realScale = (maxOffsetDistance + verticalOffset * (1 - scale)) / (maxOffsetDistance * 1f);
        }
        viewHelper.setViewOffsetScale(realScale);
    }

    private int getMaxOffset(ViewHelper viewHelper, float scale) {
        int scaleViewHeight = (int) (scale * viewHelper.getViewHeight());
        int offsetTitleDistance = scaleViewHeight >= mTitleHeight ? 0 : (mTitleHeight - scaleViewHeight) / 2;
        int marginTop = viewHelper.getMarginTitleTop() >= offsetTitleDistance ? offsetTitleDistance : viewHelper.getMarginTitleTop();
        return viewHelper.getLayoutBottom() - viewHelper.getScaleViewHeight(scale) - offsetTitleDistance - marginTop;
    }

    private class OffsetListenerImp implements AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            if (mTitle != null) {
                setTopAndBottomOffset(mTitle, verticalOffset);
            }
            if (mText != null) {
                setTopAndBottomOffset(mText, verticalOffset, mTextScale);
                setLeftAndRightOffset(mText, verticalOffset, mTextScale);
                setViewScale(mText, verticalOffset, mTextScale);
            }
            if (mImg != null) {
                setTopAndBottomOffset(mImg, verticalOffset, mImgScale);
                setLeftAndRightOffset(mImg, verticalOffset, mImgScale);
                setViewScale(mImg, verticalOffset, mImgScale);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setImgTitleMarginTop(int top) {
        if (mImg != null) {
            getViewOffsetHelper(mImg).setMarginTitleTop(top);
        }
    }

    public void setImgTitleMarginLeft(int left) {
        if (mImg != null) {
            getViewOffsetHelper(mImg).setMarginTitleLeft(left);
        }
    }

    public void setTextTitleMarginTop(int top) {
        if (mText != null) {
            getViewOffsetHelper(mText).setMarginTitleTop(top);
        }
    }

    public void setImgTextMarginLeft(int left) {
        if (mText != null) {
            getViewOffsetHelper(mText).setMarginTitleLeft(left);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the content_scolling.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#cccccc"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="nczz.cn.helloworld.ScrollingActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling">
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/large_text" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Here is the java:

```
package nczz.cn.helloworld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ScrollingActivity extends Activity {
    LinearLayout titleTxt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);
        initViews();
        setTitleBarHeight();
    }

    private void initViews(){
        titleTxt= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.test_title);
    }


    private void setTitleBarHeight(){
        WindowManager manager=getWindowManager();
        int height=manager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params=titleTxt.getLayoutParams();
        params.height=height/12;
        titleTxt.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

Comment: how did you fix this

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure but u can use following code according to view inside nested scrollview

```
viewlayoutInsidescrollview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

in java class